# Can't save PIL image in python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, pytorch

I'm trying to run code from here https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/master/fast_neural_style, I run the following command from the terminal `python neural_style/neural_style.py eval --content-image ./images/content-images/amber.jpg --model ./saved_models/mosaic.pth --output-image a.jpg --cuda 0`, where `a.jpg` is output image, but every time I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neural_style/neural_style.py", line 240, in <module>
    main()
  File "neural_style/neural_style.py", line 236, in main
    stylize(args)
  File "neural_style/neural_style.py", line 150, in stylize
    utils.save_image(args.output_image, output[0])
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\fast_neural_style\neural_style\utils.py", line 19, in save_image
    img.save(filename)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1991, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a.jpg'
```

I tried to prescribe before `a.jpg` full path with slashes and backslashes, but every time this error still appears.

I launched the following script with a command `python test.py` from the terminal:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
text = "test image"
color = (0, 0, 120)
img = Image.new('RGB', (100, 50), color)
imgDrawer = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
imgDrawer.text((10, 20), text)
img.save("pil-example.png")
```

There was again an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    img.save("pil-example.png")
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1966, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pil-example.png'
```

But when I launched this script in a `jupiter-notebook`, it worked without errors.

I use: Windows 10, Python 3.7.1, Pillow 5.3.0.

I would be grateful for any advice in solving this problem!

Comment: could you try give a fixed path ? like: `C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\image.png`

Comment: When I copy paste your code into my Windows 10 it works as expected. Pillow 5.4.1, and Python 3.5.0. You can also try
`with open(filepath, 'w') as f:`
`img.save(f)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows 10 make sure to turn off the filesystem access setting, under Ransomware Protection. The setting should be located under *Windows Security* > *Virus and Threat Protection* > *Ransomware Protection* > Turn off *Controlled Filesystem Access*.

The setting prohibits any unauthorized program or script from altering files on your system. In theory, running your script as an admin should also solve the immediate issue. However, turning off the setting also saves you from the hassle in the future.